# (Org mode) Copy to clipboard without asterisks and tags?

Tags: org-mode, clipboard

Do you know any "easy" way to copy to clipboard a region from an org-mode document without asterisks and tags:

```
* Header :tag1:
text
```

so it would appear in the clipboard as:

```
Header
text
```

Comment: Note that tags *cannot* contain dashes. See [Tags](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tags.html): `Tags are normal words containing letters, numbers, ‘_’, and ‘@’.`

Comment: Two methods: 1) if we assume that the region is a subtree, you can export it as text to a buffer (use appropriate options to export only what you need) and then use `clipboard-kill-region` on the resulting buffer. 2) copy the region to a temp buffer, use a couple of `replace-regexp` to get rid of the asterisks and the tags (or,  from Lisp, use the `(while (re-search-forward REGEXP nil t) ...)` idiom as suggested in the doc string of `replace-regexp`) and then use `clipboard-kill-region` on the temp buffer contents.

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected the tag. I was hoping for find something that wouldn't involve the extra step of creating and copying it into a separate buffer. It's okay if there's nothing built yet (I may try to create a new command for that then).

Comment: I think you should try @dalanicolai's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [kill-transform-function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Kill-Options.html) to transform the string before copying it (see its docstring for more info) as follows:

```lisp
(defun org-no-frills-copy (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((kill-transform-function (lambda (text)
                                   (replace-regexp-in-string "^*+ \\|:[[:alnum:]:]*:" "" text))))
    (copy-region-as-kill beg end)))
```

Now you can use this new command on a selected region to achieve what you want.

Alternatively, you could configure `kill-transform-function` as a buffer local value (in org buffers), if you want to transform text before killing in general (then you don't have to define your own custom command).

As mentioned in the comments, this version might not copy the text to the clipboard. In that case, I guess you can simply replace the `copy-region-as-kill` with `clipboard-kill-ring-save`, or alternatively, check the values of the `interprogram-cut-function` and the `select-enable-clipboard` variables which define the behavior of `copy-region-as-kill` (see its docstring).

Comment: That's good, but incomplete I think: it doesn't get the string to the clipboard, only to the kill ring.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for pointing it out. I did not consider this, indeed. However, for me (on Fedora), when I use this command starting from `emacs -q`, it already seems to copy to the kill-ring, i.e. I can paste in e.g. gedit using `C-v`. Anyway, I have updated the answer with a likely solution.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right: the doc string of `copy-region-as-kill` mentions `interprogram-cut-function` which is non-nil by default, so it may do exactly what the OP wants. You'll now have to edit your answer again (apologies for that!) but it's good to have a definitive answer.

Comment: Actually, I don't know if you are right, but I may just be confused: I can't get it to paste the right thing in `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: I *was* confused: it seems to work the way you describe it.

Comment: Well, I wasn't aware of the `interprogram-cut-function` and the `select-enable-clipboard` variables. No problem to update the answer. Thanks for checking and feedback!

Comment: The reason It didn't work for me was because I had set `select-enable-clipboard` to `nil`. I wonder if there is any value in doing that or whether I'm shooting myself in the foot. Now I have to do work to figure it out :-)

Comment: Thanks, it's working for me, but could we change `copy-region-as-kill` to `clipboard-kill-ring-save` as suggested in the comments? I couldn't get the former to work. I've tried `org-copy-visible` as well, but it also didn't work.

Comment: Well, in most cases, the current answer should work alright. For the other cases, I have already added the information about `clipboard-kill-ring-save` and the other options. I think as a whole the answer is fine/complete as it is now :)

Comment: @DanielKrajnik check the setting of `select-enable-clipboard`: see my comment above, but it should work with the default setting of `t`.

Comment: Sure, fair enough.